# How do I create a "copy" of a build with the number from another project pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Because of the limitation of Azure Test Plans not being able to choose a build from a different project, I was wondering if it is possible to create a pipeline that would at least clone the build number from another project.

Here's the narrative:

> There's a project `ProjA` with pipeline `P1` that generates a build number using the following line
>
> ```yaml
> name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
> ```

I want it such that:

> Another project `ProjB` has a pipeline `P1` which matches the name in `ProjA` gets triggered so that there's a build recorded whenever `ProjA.P1` is successful and have the build recorded with the same name as the build run from `ProjA.P1`

*UPDATE* note I am looking specifically for `ProjA.P1` and not whatever would've triggered `ProjA.P1`.  The original accepted answer works for the simple case where `ProjA.P1` is triggered from the `ProjA.P1` pipeline.

However, if `ProjA.P1` has `triggers: none` and uses `resources.pipelines` to trigger it's build it uses the build number of the referenced pipeline rather than `ProjA.P1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set a pipeline completion trigger to [Trigger one pipeline after another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops). (`ProjB.P1` is triggered when `ProjA.P1` completes.)

We can get the trigger build name using the resource variable `$(resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName)` in YAML. (It will retrieve the `buildNumber` of the pipeline `ProjA.P1` in pipeline.) See [Pipeline resource metadata as predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipeline-resource-metadata-as-predefined-variables) for details.

Then using the [UpdateBuildNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number) logging command (`##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]build number`) to update the build number of the `ProjB.P1`.

`ProjB.P1` YAML for your reference:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: ProjA-Trigger  # Any alias here
    source: P1               # The real pipeline name (ProjA.P1 here)
    project: ProjA           # Project ProjA
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - refs/heads/main

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(resources.pipeline.ProjA-Trigger.runName)"'
```

Comment: this works for most cases but fails on one namely if ProjA is triggered by another project lets call it ProjC, it uses ProjC's build ID rather than ProjA.  I think I'll try to make a more specific question for that scenario or clarify on the OP.